# django-newsletter - no runjobs in manage.py commands?

Tags: python, django

Hi I'm [reading the docs](http://django-newsletter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html) for using django-newsletter.

And it says to call the following admin command to actually send the emails:

```
./manage.py runjob submit
```

In other parts of the docs it says `runjobs` instead of `runjob`.

Anyways, I'm not seeing either runjob or runjobs in the list of commands `./manage.py help`, even though the `'newsletter'` app is in `installed_apps` and I can access it in the admin.

What am I missing?

Comment: "runjob", to run a single job
"runjobs",to  run all hourly/daily/weekly/monthly jobs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing django_extensions in `INSTALLED_APPS`. The actual requirements for django-newsletter in INSTALLED_APPS are:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'sorl.thumbnail',
    'django_extensions',
    'newsletter',
    ...
)
```